# trying to find and replace a string using perl

Tags: perl

in perl, I am trying to open a file , find a string, replace the string, and close the file.  I have scoured the internet, and this is what I have come up with:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -w
  #  use warnings;  

    my $oldUrl = "someString";
    my $newUrl = "someOtherString";
    $file = "someFile";
    open (MYFILE,"$file") or die "Can't open '$file': $!";
    while(my $row = <MYFILE>){
            if($row =~ /$oldUrl/)
            {
                    $row = "$newUrl";
                    print MYFILE $row;
            }
    }
    close(MYFILE);
```

this does nothing except print to screen the text: someString.  I cant get the newUrl to get actually written in the file,  what am i missing?

how would i do all files in a dir that end in .cfg:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;

my $directory = '/tftpboot';

my $oldUrl = "account.1.sip_server_host = s150133.trixbox.fonality.com";
my $newUrl = "account.1.sip_server_host = 162.221.24.130";
 ....
  .....
```

Comment: `open(FOO, $file)` opens `$file` for reading, but you're also trying to write to it. That won't work. Also, this won't fix your particular issue, but in general, you should use the safer, three-argument form of `open` and lexical filehandles: `open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read: [perlfaq5 - How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

I would recommend using [`$INPLACE_EDIT`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to handle the opening and closing of the file for you.  However, other methods are listed in the above reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = "someFile";
my $oldUrl = "someString";
my $newUrl = "someOtherString";

local @ARGV = $file;
local $^I = '.bak';
while (<>) {
    s/.*$oldUrl.*/$newUrl/;   # Replacing the whole line seems odd, but it's what you did in your example.
    print;
}
#unlink "$file$^I"; #Optionally delete backup
```

Comment: Typically `sed` would have barfed on those delimiters if the variables contained the delimiter characters. Odd that `perl` didn't complain.

Comment: Miller.  how would i do this with a whole directory? see edit.

Comment: To process an entire directory, you simply need to load it using `opendir` and `readdir`, and remember to specify the full path information when attempting to modify the file.  Alternatively, you could use a module like [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) to work in a more platform independent way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one-liner to replace string in a file:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/someString/someOtherString/g' someFile
```

Comment: Yea,  the only problem is I need to loop through a bunch of files.. So I think it needs to be a script?

Comment: instead of `someFile`, you can also use `*.txt`